# Custom Content Control doesn't show up content template

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I created a control that inherits from ContentControl and wrote style in XAML:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:ButtonPopup}">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

When I want to use my control like below I don't see any content

```
<controls:ButtonPopup Width="100"
                      Height="100">
                <Button Content="button"></Button>
</controls:ButtonPopup>
```

Everything works if I use my style in standard content control

```
<ContentControl Style="{StaticResource PopupContentStyle2}">
                <Button Content="button"></Button>
</ContentControl>

<Style x:Key="PopupContentStyle2" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border Width="100" Height="100">

                            <StackPanel Width="100" Height="100">
                                <TextBlock Text="SDADASDSADA" />
                                <ContentPresenter Width="100" Height="100" Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}" />
                            </StackPanel>

                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

What is the problem with my control?

Comment: A copy/paste of your code into a new project along with `public class ButtonPopup : ContentControl { }` works fine, so I suspect the issue is actually within your `ButtonPopup` implementation. What does that custom control look like?

Comment: @Rachel , thank you, your answer gave me a clue to find the problem. I was overriding the default value of the DefaultStyleKey in static contructor like this:
DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ButtonPopup), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ButtonPopup)));

Control works without this. Why can't I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You have a template for the content which again references the content, you should not do that. You should instead set the `Control.Template`.

The template is not even being applied because you already supply a `UIElement` which does not need to be templated. `ContentTemplates` are supposed to be used to template data.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the `ContentTemplate` you probably wanted to set the `Template` of the derived ContentControl. A TemplateBinding works in a ControlTemplate.

```
<Style TargetType="controls:ButtonPopup">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:ButtonPopup">
                <Border>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

It's also not clear why exactly there is a StackPanel with only one child inside a Border.